# Alpha Mask Extraction process Objective C implementation 

Tags: objective-c, alpha, mask

Do you have an Objective C implementation equivalent to ImageMagick's command :

```
convert -alpha Extract -type optimize -strip -quality 60 +dither Source.png Alpha.jpg
```

I was not able to find any solution right now.
I m looking for an AlphaExtractor snippet that would extract the alpha from a png and save it to JPG Grayscale

The mask is created using the code snippet :

```
CGImageRef createMaskWithImage(CGImageRef image)
{
    int maskWidth               = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    int maskHeight              = CGImageGetHeight(image);
    //  round bytesPerRow to the nearest 16 bytes, for performance's sake
    int bytesPerRow             = (maskWidth + 15) & 0xfffffff0;
    int bufferSize              = bytesPerRow * maskHeight;

    //  we use CFData instead of malloc(), because the memory has to stick around
    //  for the lifetime of the mask. if we used malloc(), we'd have to
    //  tell the CGDataProvider how to dispose of the memory when done. using
    //  CFData is just easier and cleaner.

    CFMutableDataRef dataBuffer = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    CFDataSetLength(dataBuffer, bufferSize);

    //  the data will be 8 bits per pixel, no alpha
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace  = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericGray);//CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef ctx            = CGBitmapContextCreate(CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(dataBuffer),
                                                        maskWidth, maskHeight,
                                                        8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
    //  drawing into this context will draw into the dataBuffer.
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, maskWidth, maskHeight), image);
    CGContextRelease(ctx);

    //  now make a mask from the data.
    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider  = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(dataBuffer);
    CGImageRef mask                 = CGImageMaskCreate(maskWidth, maskHeight, 8, 8, bytesPerRow,
                                                        dataProvider, NULL, FALSE);

    CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CFRelease(dataBuffer);

    return mask;
}
```

and saved :

```
-(void)_saveJPEGImage:(CGImageRef)imageRef path:(NSString *)path {

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]; 
    CFURLRef fileUrlRef=(CFURLRef)fileURL;

    CFMutableDictionaryRef mSaveMetaAndOpts = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(nil, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,  &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    CFDictionarySetValue(mSaveMetaAndOpts, kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7]); // set the compression quality here
    CFDictionarySetValue(mSaveMetaAndOpts, kCGImageDestinationBackgroundColor, kCGColorClear);

    CGImageDestinationRef dr = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL (fileUrlRef, kUTTypeJPEG , 1, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dr, imageRef, mSaveMetaAndOpts);
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(dr);
    CFRelease(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A really quick an dirty working solution :

Assuming we have a 32bytes raw data (if not the code need to be adapted)

1- we iterate through the bytes by +4 steps and alter the r,g,b components.

```
 CGImageRef ref=CGImageCreateCopy([_imageView image]);
NSData *data        = (NSData *)CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(ref));
char   *bytes       = (char *)[data bytes];

int i;
for( i= 0; i < [data length]; i += 4)
{
    int r = i;
    int g = i+1;
    int b = i+2;
    int a = i+3;

    bytes[r]   = 0; 
    bytes[g]   = 0;
    bytes[b]   = 0;
    bytes[a]   = bytes[a];
}
```

2- We create a new RGBA (32Bit) image reference with the "modified data" :

```
size_t width                    = CGImageGetWidth(ref);
size_t height                   = CGImageGetHeight(ref);
size_t bitsPerComponent         = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(ref);
size_t bitsPerPixel             = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(ref);
size_t bytesPerRow              = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(ref);

CGColorSpaceRef colorspace      = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo         = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(ref);
CGDataProviderRef provider      = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,bytes, [data length], NULL);

CGImageRef newImageRef = CGImageCreate (
                                        width,
                                        height,
                                        bitsPerComponent,
                                        bitsPerPixel,
                                        bytesPerRow,
                                        colorspace,
                                        bitmapInfo,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        false,
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault
                                        );
```

3- We save this new 32Bytes image reference to a jpeg file. 
The generated JPG will be usable as a mask.

We could do it a cleaner way by creating an 8Bit context and writing the "alpha component" only.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

```
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, maskWidth, maskHeight), image);
```

doesn't extract the alpha, it just alpha-composites the image onto a black background.
If the image is black with transparency then an all-black image would be the expected output.

and:

```
CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(maskWidth, maskHeight, 8, 8, bytesPerRow,
                                    dataProvider, NULL, FALSE);
```

You're treating this mask you create like a real image. If you replace this line with

```
CGImageRef mask = CGImageCreate(maskWidth, maskHeight, 8, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, 0,
                                dataProvider, NULL, FALSE, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

Then you will get a greyscale version of your image (see problem 1)

Comment: That I'm not quite sure of, I'll try to play around with it a little later, unless someone more knowledgable jumps in.

Comment: @Chaosmos Great, is there any chance you could post what worked for you as an answer? It helps future people with the same problem. (Questions are normally only deleted if they are of no value to the community, and this is an interesting problem that others may have as well.)

Comment: My answer was refused by Stackoverflow (you cannot answer your own question if your account is new)